# ios security image files in document directory

Tags: ios, security

I need to secure files in document directory on iOS especially images. I don't want user can download images in document directory by Xcode or iExplorer app.
I research on iOS 6, Apple support security by passcode of device. But it's not as i expected.

Are you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the `NSData` method `writeToFile:options:error:`
with one of the options `NSDataWritingOptions` which will write the file encrypted:
`NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete`,
`NSDataWritingFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen` or
`NSDataWritingFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication`

Otherwise you can use the `CommonCrypto` functions to encrypt/decrypt yourself. That is not really hard except for securing and handling the key and securing the key is the most important part and the hardest to get right.

Comment: but how may i use this.

Comment: If you are worried about a user downloading the images by using the iExplorer app, given that they have paired the phone with the computer and can unlock the device, they will bypass iOS data protection and be able to look at the contents of the documents folder for your specific app (ie your images). So as zaph suggests, CommonCrypto is a good solution. Where to hide the encryption key? You can obfuscate that in the app (not good but prevents casual observation of the files), or the the key could be sent to the app from a server when the app starts up (better).

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way to encrypt your file is Exclusive-OR.

The Basic principle is A xor B xor B = A.

More from [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)

Comment: Xor with what? There is a CTR mode but it requires a nonce and each nonce can only be used once, it tends to be very insecure in practice.

Comment: @Zaph Select a uint64_t key , then compose 8 byte from file stream as a part to Xor with the key and save the result in another file. It is not very securable but it is easy to encrypt and decrypt.

Comment: I think the key point is a tradeoff between easy and secure: **don't**. The first rule of secure cryptography is never design your own encryption. As for easy, the easiest way is to use the `NSDataWritingOptions` of `NSData`.

Comment: Using NSDataWritingOptions of NSData seems better solution, but I haven't used it.

Comment: @Zaph hmm... I am not questioner.